dependency key coming as undefined
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[enter link description here][2]
I'm trying to check the start date and end date dependency error handling but getting 'startDate' coming as undefined in endDate schema.
    startDate: Yup.date()
      .default(() => new Date())
      .transform((value, originalValue, context) => {
        if (context.isType(value)) {
          return value
        }
        const result = dayjs(originalValue, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
        return result.isValid() ? result.toDate() : new Date('')
      })
      .typeError('Please Enter valid Date Format')
      .required('Field is Mandatory')
      .min(
        dayjs('22-04-2024', 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        'Minimum Value'
      ),
    endDate: Yup.date()
      .default(() => new Date())
      .transform((value, originalValue, context) => {
        if (context.isType(value)) {
          return value
        }
        const result = dayjs(originalValue, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
        return result.isValid() ? result.toDate() : new Date('')
      })
      .typeError('Please Enter valid Date Format')
       .required('Field is Mandatory')
      .when('startDate', ([startDate], schema) => {
        console.log(startDate)
        if (startDate) {
          console.log('startDate', startDate)
          return schema
            .min(
              dayjs(startDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
              'Minimum Value'
            )
            .typeError('Please Enter Valid Value')
        }
        return schema
      }),
  })```


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/MBKmCUup.png
  [2]: https://github.com/jquense/yup?tab=readme-ov-file#schemawhenkeys-string--string-builder-object--values-any-schema--schema-schema

